# 最近の規格書改定で size_t に新しい(ハードウエア的)意味が増えましたか？

Tags: c++, c

[sizeof(size_t)未満の幅の型の、メモリ上隣り合った変数に関して、マルチスレッドプログラムはデータ競合なく読み書きできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/67969/)

上記の投稿においては `size_t` 型はハードウエア的に特殊な意味を持つ（バス幅ないしはキャッシュバウンダリー) ように書かれています。ですが、オイラの認識では C99 6.5.3.4 ならびに C++03 5.3.3 で「 `sizeof` の結果は `size_t` 型の定数である」とだけあってハードウエアの機能に関係する型ではありません。

最近の C/C++ 規格改定で `size_t` の機能にハードウエアに関係する文言が追加されているでしょうか?
(すんません最近の規格書がフォローできていないっす)

Comment: もとの質問が誤って用語を使っただけだと思います。CPUのバス幅によってアトミックに操作できる変数のビット数のことを、かっこよく言おうとして間違ったのかなと、思ってました。

Comment: 元の質問をしたものです。こちらを参照していました。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843365/how-to-detect-machine-word-size-in-c-c alignas(size_t)に意味はないのですね。知りませんでした。かっこよく言おうとしたという指摘がありますが、間違っていただけで私はこの方法しか知らなかったというだけです。なかなかトゲのある言い方をされますね。

Comment: 規格書マニアとしては「 `size_t` は `sizeof` の返す値の型」と定義されているってだけですのでお気になさらず。たまたまそれがハードウエア実装上の「ワードサイズ」の代用になるかもしれなくても、です。「ワードサイズ」には万人の合意する基準がないので混乱があるのは当然のことです。 8086 CPU は 16bit で良いとして 8088 CPU は 8bit なのか 16bit なのかはいまだに合意がありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 最近の C/C++ 規格改定で `size_t` の機能にハードウエアに関係する文言が追加されているでしょうか?

そのような改定は行われてないはずです。（少なくともC++2aドラフト、C2xドラフトでは。）

---

C++2a [support.types.layout]/p3

> The type `size_­t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([expr.sizeof]).

C2x §7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>/p1

> `size_t`
> which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

Comment: やはりそうですよね・でも `size_t` とハードウエアが関係してるような質問を他の掲示板でも見た記憶があるんですよ。誰かがどこかでそんな記事書いてるとしか思えないっす。

Comment: `size_t`型で該当環境におけるメモリアドレス空間を表現できる（64bit OSなら64bit幅）という事実から、一部で誤った拡大解釈がなされているのかも？